# How can I recover the space in a qcow2 file after deleting snapshots, while retaining remaining snapshots?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, snapshot, qcow2

I have a virtual machine that started out with 5 snapshots 1,2,3,4,5.

I used **qemu-img** to delete snapshots 1,2,3.  Snapshots 4 and 5 are still needed and were not deleted.

**How can I release the space used by snapshots 1,2,3 and retain snapshots 4 and 5?**

I have spent a lot of time searching for a solution, and the solutions I have found
fit into one of two patterns:

**Use qemu-img convert** (Deleted needed snapshots)

`qemu-img convert -O qcow2  Linux.qcow2 Linux_s.qcow2`

This reduces the space used by Linux.qcow2, but deletes snapshots 4 and 5.

**Copy the VM and use virt-sparsify** (Doesn't recover any space)

`cp Linux.qcow2 TEST.qcow2`

`sudo virt-sparsify --in-place TEST.qcow2`

It retains the two undeleted snapshots, but doesn't recover the space that was originally occupied by snapshots 1,2,3.

How can I recover the space in a qcow2 file after deleting snapshots, while retaining remaining snapshots?

Comment: Why do you believe that there is any space left to "recover"?

Comment: The VM is essentially clean, it's updated, and snapshotted.  I restore the napshot on boot at regular intervals, so the delta for each snapshot is essentially what changes on each distribution update.

Answer (score 0):

qcow2 files are sparse files. On filesystems that support sparse files they can take a lot less space on disk than the size of the file.

If you delete a snapshot the size as reported by `ls -l` doesn't change, but the amount of free space on the disk as reported by `df` does change.

Almost all filesystems support sparse files. FAT and NFSv3 are probably the only common filesystems that don't.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the snapshots 1,2,3, the files are deleted, but it doesn't indicate any released space because it is not real deletion. Files are just marked so that deletion will be finished quickly.

If you would like to release the space of the deleted snapshots, you can convert the qcow2 file but you have to fulfill the qcow2 file with 0 via dd command before that:

```
$dd if=/dev/zero of=~/junk
dd: writing to `/home/***/junk': No space left on device
$rm junk
```

then convert the qcow2 file

```
qemu-img convert -O qcow2  Linux.qcow2 Linux_s.qcow2
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/575323)